# Configurable Product an Inventory

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

i have one configurable product and it doesn't show in frontend.
The reason is, there is a quantity of 0 in products overview in backend. But i can't change it in inventory.
In inventory, i choose Manage Stock = yes. But no configuration for quantity is showing.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add atleast one **Simple Product** as an **associated product** with your **Configurable product** for it to appear on Front End.

Go to **Manage Product**, and Select your Configurable Product. Select Last tab: "**Associated Products**".

Now either create new Simple Product by clicking on "**Create Empty**" or Select already added Simple Products.

Comment: i have two simple products and then one ConfigProduct. On tab "Associated Products" i can only create new empty, but i can not see the both simple products to choose one of them.

Comment: and with "quick create" its create a new simple product, but no product is associated with the ConfigProdukt :(

Comment: Once you 'Quick Create' product, do make sure you click on "Save" for configurable product.
Also, you can click on already created Configurable product, and Associated Products. Then you will see a tab 
"Quick simple product creation"   
(second tab after "Create Simple Associated Product")

This tab can be used to create same simple products quickly and you can create multiple products using this feature. BUT again make sure you "Save" your configurable PRoduct after creating these new simple products.
Let me know if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

To make a configurable product visible in the front end you should only have to do the following.

- On the inventory tab, mark availability as 'In Stock'.
- Ensure there is a simple product associated.
- Ensure the simple product has availability marked as 'In Stock'.
- Ensure the simple product has qty set above the out of stock quantity
  threshold.
- Ensure both the simple product and configurable product is associated to the correct website.
- On the General tab of the configurable make sure Visibility is set to
  something other than not visible individually.
- Re-index (System > Index Management > Select All > Submit.

Comment: +1 Excellent post. Add these two steps for bonus points: Ensure simple product is set to "not individually visible", not required but highly recommended. Second, ensure that configurable and it's simples all have different URL keys. [Here's the why](http://www.dnd.fr/2012/09/magento-patch-how-to-optimize-re-index-processing-time-for-url-rewrite/)